# HTML / CSS Modules - Best Practice?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm starting to pull out independent pieces of HTML into their own files and include them using the PHP `include` keyword.

I have a CSS file about 1500 lines long.  What' I'm considering doing is placing embedded CSS with the corresponding HTML files.

Of course leaving components that are used in different HTML blocks.

This way I have modular HTML / CSS blocks that I just include on the server using PHP `include`

Is this best practice? Yes/No, Why

Comment: What are you hoping to gain by this?

Comment: B.C my app is small I have all my modules in one file...which I actually concatenate with Base64 images, and JavaScript...conceptually it is all separate...but when I send it, I send it in a clump to limit HTTP requests...also it is cached on the client...a clump cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers cache CSS files... because of this loading one large CSS file isn't a big deal.

If you wanted to make it super efficient, you could split the css into their different modules.  Then create a "build system" that checks which modules are being used and creates one CSS file (minified even) with only the necessary CSS.

Comment: Javascript - jQuery does something like this....if only I were 5 people instead of 1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't embed your CSS into the HTML file directly, but have an external stylesheet for each file. In much the same way you should keep your JS separate from your HTML, this keeps your CSS separate too. Then all you need to do to include your CSS is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/style.css">
```

Which you would put below any global stylesheet includes. This also keeps page-specific CSS confined to loading on *only that page*, so no bandwidth is wasted transferring styles you will never use.

---

However, if you're `include()`ing say, 15 files into your page, you don't want to make 15 requests for CSS files. In this case, you should group them into larger files to reduce the number of requests required.

Comment: If he has 20 "modules" loaded, thats 20 separate connections that need to be made.  Not very efficient.

Comment: This could produce several requests for external CSS files.  Generally, one should try to keep that limited if possible.

Comment: My understanding of the question was that the OP would be using an HTML/CSS pair of files for separate _pages_, not separate modules.

Comment: @Galen - it may not be the most efficient at first, but once they're cached, it won't matter for subsequent page loads

Comment: @JamWaffles Hiro's post isn't very clear, so I see what you're saying.

Comment: I was aiming for easier to maintain CSS/HTML...but did not want to loose efficiency...a 1500 line CSS file is alot to look through if you can't remember the exact identifier.

Comment: Developing w/ a modular approach and using a build system is the best solution...browser caching does not work well....so I built my own...but still on the initial load I only want to send one file...

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to consider here to see what's best for you:

- Does your server currently send the http-gzipped version of the CSS files to make it as fast as possible?
- Did you minify the CSS to see how small you can get it (several tools out there minify files for you, like YUI Compressor)?
- Sending the CSS as snippets will mean the file can't be cached by the browser; check if that's worth it. It depends on a number of variables, like average pages per visitor (a look into Google Analytics or another statistics software may help), size of chunks vs overall CSS size, etc.
- There may or may not be minimal server computation overhead for serving chunks with PHP as opposed to flat files without PHP; check if that's relevant to your situation.
- Do you serve media-dependent CSS? If so, ensure that the chunks get served only when needed (e.g. a mobile device may only need the mobile chunks).

Comment: good stuff...I proudly cache my own static content using localStorage.